# Is there a Criteria API for Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

since i can't find anything in the docs and the information out there seems to be restricted - what is the best way to achieve functionality equal to the Criteria API from spring data in Spring Data JDBC?

Is there any alternative or do i have to fall back to something like JdbcTemplate?

Comment: There is nothing like a Criteria API. But checkout https://jooq.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no Criteria API and there are no plans to create one.

But you can combine Spring Data JDBC with other libraries that provide such an API, like JOOQ or Querydsl by writing a custom method.